# ASP.net c# SQL. If record combination exists in table, delete the records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

i have a button on image detail page that allows the user to add said image to "favorites" which currently work, i just select the current `querystring ID` as the image `id`, and the `session["bruger_id"]` as the users `Id` and insert it into a table called `"favoritter"`

how i do it:

```
protected void Button_favorit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["bruger_id"] != null)
    {


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString1"].ToString();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        int nID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString());

        cmd.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO Favoritter"
            + "(FK_bruger_id, FK_billede_id) VALUES (@fk_bruger_id, @FK_billede_id)";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FK_billede_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FK_bruger_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["bruger_id"];


        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



        conn.Close();

        Label_favorit.Text = "Billedet blev tilføjet til Favoritter.";

    }
    else
    {
        Label_favorit.Text = "Logind for at tilføje som favorit";
    }
}
```

**so my question is:**
if the user already added the image to favorites, he currently can do it again and again, and add the same image as a favorite more than once, which is not good.
so i want the button to say "Remove from favorites" if the `fk_user_id` has already favorited the `FK_image_id`

but i dont know how to check if the combination of `fk_user_id` and `fk_image_id` already exists. If it does, it should `DELETE FROM` instead of `INSERT INTO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id FROM Favoritter WHERE (FK_user_id = @fk_user_id and FK_image_id = @fk_image_id)";
...
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then check data returned.

Comment: Well, both of you guys got it right :) thx alot for the fast support. i made it work with what you guys said. I added the code you suggest in page_load where if the combination exsist the "buttonRemove" is visible, if the combination dosnt exists "buttonAddToFavorites" is visible :) Thx again !

Answer (score 0):

Perform a select query on that combination of userid and imageid. If anything is returned, delete it (using that returned record id- will be null if combination does not exist) and enter a new record.

I think Logically Deleting the record might help as well, but that will require structure changes...

Answer (score 0):

You can make this task in one query. The command text will look like this:

```
cmd.CommandText =
          "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Favoritter"
        + "WHERE FK_bruger_id = @fk_bruger_id AND FK_billede_id = @FK_billede_id)"
        + "BEGIN"
        + "INSERT INTO Favoritter"
        + "(FK_bruger_id, FK_billede_id) VALUES (@fk_bruger_id, @FK_billede_id)";
        + "END"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FK_billede_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = nID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FK_bruger_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["bruger_id"];
```

Comment: That looks promising. i will try that when i get home. Thx alot :)